# What kind of expression is this?

Tags: php

i'm noob with php and i was wondering what that expression mean:

```
$extra_adults = ($num_adults > $people) ? $num_adults-$people : 0;
```

can someone explain me please?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Google "PHP ?:", this is the ternary operator, many languages have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a Ternary operator statement. E.g.

```
$x = $valid ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

It will assign yes to $x if $valid is true and no if $valid is false.

So, as per your statement which is:

```
$extra_adults = ($num_adults > $people) ? $num_adults-$people : 0;
```

If `$num_adults` is greater than $people then it will do `$num_adults` -`$people` and assing the result to `$extra_adults`, else it will assign 0 to `$extra_adults`.

Comment: Thank you very much, very good explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This is called ternary operator. A short form of if else statment in php.

Readmore at this link http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary